# How to prevent 404 errors on glassfish4

Tags: glassfish-4

My application is running on glassfish4 and I keep getting 404 errors. When I restart glassfish, the problem is resolved.

How can I figure out why I'm getting 404 errors?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Be specific, the more concise the info you provide, the easier it will be to answer or at least point you in the right direction.